# My check out page is stuck on billing information in installed themes

Tags: magento

I am encountered with a strange problem that when i do my checkout process with default theme installed then it will properly running but when i apply other themes then my checkout process stuck at billing information. I have tried every thing but this problem is not solved. so any one can help me in this problem.